# * Suitescript 2.0 * How can update the status of a custom record from Map Reduce script?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

So all i want to do is if the m/r script fails, update the corresponding dropdown value on custom record from m/r script.

How to do this in SuiteScript 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the summary step to get the errors that occurred in your Map Reduce script. The following code should help you achieve this:

```
function summarize(summary) {
    handleErrors(summary);
    handleSummaryOutput(summary.output);

    //*********** HELPER FUNCTIONS ***********

    function handleErrors(summary) {
        var errorsArray = getErrorsArray(summary);
        if(!errorsArray || !errorsArray.length){
            log.debug('No errors encountered');
            return;
        }

        for (var i in errorsArray) {
            log.error('Error ' + i, errorsArray[i]);
        }

        if(errorsArray && errorsArray.length){
            //
            //INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
            //
        }

        return errorsArray;

        //*********** HELPER FUNCTIONS ***********
        function getErrorsArray(summary){
            var errorsArray = [];

            if (summary.inputSummary.error){
                log.audit('Input Error', summary.inputSummary.error);
                errorsArray.push('Input Error | MSG: ' + summary.inputSummary.error);
            }

            summary.mapSummary.errors.iterator().each(function (key, e){
                var errorString = getErrorString(e);
                log.audit('Map Error', 'KEY: ' + key + ' | ERROR: ' + errorString);
                errorsArray.push('Map Error | KEY: ' + key + ' | ERROR: ' + errorString);
                return true; //Must return true to keep looping
            });

            summary.reduceSummary.errors.iterator().each(function (key, e){
                var errorString = getErrorString(e);
                log.audit('Reduce Error', 'KEY: ' + key + ' | MSG: ' + errorString);
                errorsArray.push('Reduce Error | KEY: ' + key + ' | MSG: ' + errorString);
                return true; //Must return true to keep looping
            });

            return errorsArray;

            //*********** HELPER FUNCTIONS ***********
            function getErrorString(e){
                var errorString = '';
                var errorObj = JSON.parse(e);
                if (errorObj.type == 'error.SuiteScriptError' || errorObj.type == 'error.UserEventError'){
                    errorString = errorObj.name + ': ' + errorObj.message;
                } else {
                    errorString = e;
                }
                return errorString;
            }
        }
    }

    function handleSummaryOutput(output){
        var contents = '';
        output.iterator().each(function (key, value){
            contents += (key + ' ' + value + '\n');
            return true;
        });
        if(contents){
            log.debug('output', contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! However, i need to change value of the dropdown to error, on current record who called this map reduce. How can I do that ?

Comment: @FreeMarker12, you need to provide code sample.  If you already know the record your on, it just be pretty simple just do a nlapiSubmitField().  I'm guessing it's not that simple.  And what does m/r script fails mean? Adolfo Garaza is correct about the summary

Comment: See this one: // set the record status to complete
        var mergeRecord = record.load({
      type: 'customrecordvc_merge_vendor_request', 
      id: '12',
      isDynamic: true
  });

  mergeRecord.setText({
         fieldId: 'custrecordvc_merge_vendor_request_status',
            text: 'Complete'
        });
      
       var mergeRecordId = mergeRecord.save({
            enableSourcing: false,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false
       }); --------------> I'm trying to change the dropdown value in summary method

Comment: You need to use setValue for picklists, you gotta find out whats the id of "complete" value. Instead of loading the record and saving you are better off using submitField like so: var complete_status_id=1;record.submitFields({type:'customrecordvc_merge_vendor_request',id:12,values:{custrecordvc_merge_vendor_request_status:complete_status_id,},options:{enableSourcing:false,ignoreMandatoryFields:false}});

Comment: Thanks ! However, my question is about that id:12.. I need to get the current record id instead of hardcoding it and not able to do it

Comment: You are going to have to get creative. I don't know of any way that you can pass a parameter to a map reduce script. These scripts only load data from either hardcoded values or a saved search. A quick solution would be to add a new checkbox field to mark the record for processing, lets call it  "To process", then pick up the record in your map reduce script using a search for records that have the  "To process" checkbox marked. After processing you can unmark the "To process" checkbox.